# Yes or no function, arguments, and return void to cout

Tags: c++, function

So I'm fairly new to c++ and programming in general, so just for learning purposes, I am trying to extend the use of functions, but I'm not sure what do create for the arguments of my yesorno(). I created this and thought it would work, but as I understand, it always prints the return of '0' (which is also unwanted, but I understand why it does it currently) but does nothing with the variables and ends the program. Does anyone have anything that would spare me a remote crash course on everything I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int yesorno_input = NULL;
    std::cout << yesorno();
    if (yesorno_input == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "no";
    }
    std::cin.get();
}

int yesorno()
{
    int yesorno_input = NULL;
    char choice;
    std::cout << "Y\\N";
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y')
        int yesorno_input = 1;
    else if (choice == 'n')
        int yesorno_input = 0;
    else
        std::cout << "...";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Does anyone have anything that would spare me a remote crash course on everything I'm doing wrong?"_ Stack Overflow is a Q&A (more like a forum), not a place for crash courses/tutorials/mentoring (like a forum or chat room).

Comment: [This](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-4th/dp/0321563840/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404734203&sr=1-1&keywords=stroustrup) comes to mind... Or any one of myriad others...

Comment: Try `int yesorno_input = yesorno();` to capture the result of the function call in a variable. Then review the early chapters of your [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) to remind yourself how variables work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you want to get the result back from the `yesorno()` right.?
And in your program you have made some mistakes like as noted in below code.
And as you want to have a parametrized function `yesorno()` try following:

```
#include <iostream>
int yesorno(char); // declaration of function yesorno

int main()
{
    int yesorno_input = NULL;
    char choice;

    // here you want to get input from user right? 
    std::cout << "Y\\N";
    std::cin >> choice;

    // here you want to get the value by passing char as a parameter right?
    // so pass the char as a parameter to function yesorno

    yesorno_input  = yesorno(choice);

    // print the answer
    std::cout << yesorno_input;

    // Check for the return value by using switch statement 
    // we can use if...else ladder too but it is convenient to use switch statement
    switch(yesorno_input)
    {
      case 0: 
        std::cout << "No";
        break;
      case 1: 
        std::cout << "yes";
        break;
      default: 
        std::cout << "Invalid Input";          
    }
    std::cin.get();
}

int yesorno(char choice)
{
    // you dnt need these things as you are passing value to the function
    //int yesorno_input = NULL;
    //char choice;
    //std::cout << "Y\\N";
    //std::cin >> choice;

    // just check here for the values and enjoy the output
    if (choice == 'y')
        return 1;
    else if (choice == 'n')
        return 0;
    else            
        return -1;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Corrected version of your code. Learn to DEBUG your code. This way you will learn the fun of programming. You should know the significance of each line in your code.

```
#include <iostream>

int yesorno(){
  int yesorno_input = NULL;
  char choice;
  std::cout << "Y\\N";
  std::cin >> choice;
  if (choice == 'y')
    yesorno_input = 1;
  else if (choice == 'n')
    yesorno_input = 0;
  else
    std::cout << "...";
  std::cin.get();
  return yesorno_input;
}


int main()
{
  int yesorno_input = NULL;
  yesorno_input = yesorno();
  if (yesorno_input == 1)
  {
    std::cout << "yes";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "no";
  }
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int yesorno_input = yesorno();
    if (yesorno_input == 1)
    {
       std::cout << "yes";
    }
else
{
    std::cout << "no";
}
}

int yesorno()
{

std::cout << "Y\\N";
std::cin >> choice;
if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
    return 1;
else if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N')
   return 0;

}
```

In your code, at the end of `yerorno() function` you use `return 0;` statement. This  causes whatever the input is, return 0 to called line.

In order to correct this: 
You have to use your return value of the `yesorno` function in order to use the choice. You can do this with `yesorno_input = yesorno();`